# parsing with requests and BeautifulSoup . Why the email cannot be scraped from the link

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

*my script is not returning email field that I want to scrape from a website . Any workaround??*

```py
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = 'https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385179144187908-1'

res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

name  = soup.find('div',class_='AgentContent__name').text.strip()

location = soup.find('div',class_='AgentContent__location').text.strip()

website = soup.find('a',class_='AgentInformation__factBody').attrs['href']

print(website)

print(name)

print(location)
```

*This is what I get*

/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#f18394909d94828590859482b199949895989093949d94df929e9c

Heidi Abele

Campbell, CA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information is in the script block, u can get everything u want. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


response = requests.get('https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385179144187908-1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
json_data = json.loads(soup.find('script', {'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).get_text())
name = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['name']['full']
city = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['location']['city']
state = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['location']['state']
email = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['email']
website = json_data['props']['pageProps']['agentData']['website']
print(f"{name}, {city}, {state}, {email}, {website}")
```

OUTPUT:

```
Heidi Abele, Campbell, CA, realestates@heidiabele.com, https://heidiabelerealtor.com/
```